# ADFS 2.0 httpcontext.current.user.identity.name is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, adfs2.0, adfs

i am using ADFS 2.0 with .net 2.0 web applciation
i am trying to get httpcontext.current.user.identity.name on my web application but it comes as empty. what claims rule do i need to set to get this value?
i have tried 
Transform Incoming Claim
Incoming Claim type: AD FS 1.x UPN
Outgoing Claim Type: Name ID
Outgoing name ID format : UPN

i have also tried
send Ldap Attributes as Claims
Attribute STore:Active Directory

LDAP-Attribute                 Outgoing Claim Type
SAM-Account-Name                SamAccountName
Token-Groups- Unqailfied Names    Group
User-Principal-Name               AD FS 1.x UPN

my code used to work with ADFS 1.0 i changed the fs url to adfs2.0 and i started to see this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a pass through rule of "Name"?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to send the "Name" claim through as [nzpcmad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9922/nzpcmad) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9181703/7290). Alternatively, in your web app's WIF configuration you can set the NameClaimType to something other than the default ("Name" is the default, hence). It will then use a claim of that type to fill the Name property on the thread's principal identity.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to install a certificate for your domain in order to get the identity process working, after which you should see the claims.

Comment: Hi @JakeJ, not sure which cert is needed to be installed. im having issues on my mvc app deployed in the iis server,